# Python read NetworkManager data

Tags: python, readfile, syslog

I wrote a small script to read NetworkManager data in the syslog from my ubuntu machine.
**However the output file seems to be empty** and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance:

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import os.path


o = open("/home/user/Desktop/Python/log.txt", "w") #yourdestinationfolder

if os.path.exists("/var/log/messages"):  #messages in ubuntu is no more
    f = open("/var/log/messages", "r")

    for line in f.readlines():

            if "NetworkManager" in line:
                    o.write(line)


if os.path.exists("var/log/syslog"):
    d = open("/var/log/syslog" , "r") 

    for line in d.readline():

        if "NetworkManager" in line:
                    o.write(line)
```

snippet from syslog

```
cat syslog | grep NetworkManager

    Nov 12 16:38:33 root-garlic NetworkManager[1134]: <info>  [1478965113.9672] device (wlx00116b4ee031): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov 12 16:38:33 root-garlic kernel: [ 1291.985246] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx00116b4ee031: link is not ready
Nov 12 16:38:33 root-garlic kernel: [ 1291.985278] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
Nov 12 16:38:33 root-garlic kernel: [ 1291.985344] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic ModemManager[1071]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1': not supported by any plugin
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic kernel: [ 1294.102790] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx00116b4ee031: link is not ready
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic wpa_supplicant[1629]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic wpa_supplicant[1629]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic NetworkManager[1134]: <info>  [1478965116.1538] device (wlx00116b4ee031): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic NetworkManager[1134]: <info>  [1478965116.1540] device (wlx00116b4ee031): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Nov 12 16:38:36 root-garlic kernel: [ 1294.172125] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx00116b4ee031: link is not ready
Nov 12 16:38:38 root-garlic wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlx00116b4ee031: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Nov 12 16:38:39 root-garlic wpa_supplicant[1629]: wlx00116b4ee031: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Nov 12 16:38:39 root-garlic NetworkManager[1134]: <info>  [1478965119.4021] device (wlx00116b4ee031): supplicant interface state: ready -> inacti
```

Comment: What does `os.path.exists("/var/log/messages")` return (probably False)?

Comment: The leading slash is missing from the path in  `os.path.exists("var/log/syslog")`. However, you will probably also have a permissions issue if you don't run the script as root. See what `ls -l /var/log/syslog` prints.

Comment: BTW, there's no point doing an `if exists` test on a file you intend to open for reading. Just wrap the `open` call in a `try... except IoError:`. Also, it's more efficient to directly iterate over a file with `for line in f:` rather than reading the whole thing into a list with `f.readlines()` and then iterating over the lines. And when you `open` files without a `with` context manager you should `close` them when you're finished with them, but it's much better to use `with`.

Comment: I'm not that skilled in python if you didn't noticed and still on a learning curve with it, thnx for the input I will try this asap :)

Comment: added the slash, and still an empty output file ( I run the script as root)